# Selecting countries with different situations

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm trying to `select` two groups of countries with different situations.

```
SELECT cou.id, 
       cou.title 
FROM   continents con 
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN countries cou 
                     ON con.id = cou.continents_id 
WHERE  con.deliver = 1 
       AND con.active = 1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT cou2.id, 
       cou2.title 
FROM   countries cou2 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN continents con2 
                    ON con2.id = cou2.continents_id 
WHERE  cou2.deliver = 1 
       AND con2.deliver = 0
```

1. Continent has to be `deliver = 1` and then select all countries inside it.
2. If Continent is `deliver = 0` but there are countries with `deliver = 1` inside, then select it.

What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: is it possible to write left outer join instead of right outer join for the first part

Comment: Yes, I think it will not be a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have formatted the queries. I am not able to test it, so if you can give the schema for this, or create it at SQL fiddle, that will be great. Data is not required.

```
SELECT cou.id, 
       cou.title 
FROM   countries cou 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN continents con 
                     ON  cou.continents_id = con.id 
WHERE  (con.deliver = 1 AND con.active = 1 ) OR 
       (cou.deliver = 1 AND cou.deliver = 0)
```

Please let me know in case there are any concerns.